# Gatsby createNode only returning one node with array of data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, gatsby

I am using Gatsby node API and fetch to get data from a remote API then looping through the data with forEach. When using Gatsby develop and querying with graphQL, only one node has been created when ~30 are expected:

code:

`

```
exports.sourceNodes = async ({ 
  actions,
  createNodeId,
  createContentDigest 
}, configOptions) => {
  const NODE_TYPE = 'Job';

  const response = await fetch(
    configOptions.url,
    {
      headers: {
        jobs_key: configOptions.access_key
      },
    },
  );
  const raw_data = await response.json();
  const jobs_raw = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(raw_data));
  const jobs = jobs_raw.response.results;
  console.log(jobs);
  jobs.forEach(job => {
    actions.createNode({
      ...job,
      id: createNodeId(`${NODE_TYPE}-${job.id}`),
      parent: null,
      children: [],
      internal: {
        type: NODE_TYPE,
        content: JSON.stringify(job),
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(job)
      }
    })
  });
};
```

`

sample output when using gatsby develop and querying with graphQL:

`

```
{
  "data": {
    "allJob": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "a6f3a0ee-d213-54bd-a78c-bc86815667b5"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

`

I have tried with the same result but it seems to only return the last object in the array as a node:

`

```
await Promise.all(
    jobs.map(async (job) => createNode(await processJob(job)))
  );
```

`

sample json data:

```
{
    'Modified Date': '2022-11-03T08:30:56.910Z',
    'Created Date': '2022-11-03T08:30:56.850Z',
    'Created By': '1667463646950x933984614718435600',
    complete: false,
    location: 'San Francisco, CA, USA',
    roleTitle: 'Post Planner',
    company: '1667464234467x541822089287434240',
    listEmploymentType: [ 'Seasonal' ],
    eventYesNo: false,
    jobStatus: 'Draft',
    _id: '1667464256451x402163967653838850'
  },
  {
    'Modified Date': '2022-11-06T00:53:17.123Z',
    'Created Date': '2022-11-06T00:53:17.076Z',
    'Created By': '1667695686617x823696282359582100',
    complete: false,
    location: 'Emeryville, CA, USA',
    roleTitle: 'Some Job',
    company: '1667695985945x156747773832069120',
    listEmploymentType: [ 'Seasonal', 'Full-Time', 'Part-Time', 'Contract', 'Event' ],
    eventYesNo: false,
    jobStatus: 'Draft',
    geoLocation: {
      address: 'Emeryville, CA, USA',
      lat: 37.8395028,
      lng: -122.2892278
    },
    _id: '1667695995983x831215741492265000'
  }
```